# How to have multiple markdowns in the same gist

Tags: github, markdown, gist

I would like to create a gist in which I can present a main markdown document containing a set of links. These links will point to secondary markdowns which actually contain the code examples and technical explanations:

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/awa5114/4052ba8adb51779192a4a715a048f8ca) what I have so far. I have included two markdown files:

- `Notes.md`: contains a listing of existing secondary markdown documents
- `tree_traversal.md`: an example of such a secondary markdown

As you can see I have tried to add a link in `Notes.md` to `tree_traversal.md` using the following syntax:

```
example of a [link](tree_traversal.md)
```

However there are two issues:

1. The Gist server attempts to display both `Notes.md` and `tree_traversal.md`. This is not what I want. I want to have `Notes.md` display first, then click on the link to navigate to `tree_traversal.md`
2. When I actually click on the link I created in `Notes.md` I get a 404 Page not found error.

Is it possible to have a multi-page gist like this? If so how? If not is gist only designed to have one markdown file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mousing over the `tree_traversal.md` header we see that it is a link to

```
https://gist.github.com/awa5114/4052ba8adb51779192a4a715a048f8ca#file-tree_traversal-md
```

Try simply linking to `#file-tree_traversal-md` in `Notes.md`. This should let you link between files, though they will both still be rendered in a single view.

Gists are designed for quick snippets, not documentation. Maybe you are looking for [GitHub wikis](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/building-a-strong-community/documenting-your-project-with-wikis)? Wikis [can be cloned via Git, managed locally, and pushed back](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/building-a-strong-community/adding-or-editing-wiki-pages#adding-or-editing-wiki-pages-locally), and they render pages one at a time.

Or possibly [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/), which can be used to host static websites?

Comment: I don't know if GitHub wiki's are what I'm looking for. They seem to be designed for software documentation and this is not really what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to build a blog or small website where I can keep a record of what I'm doing and explanations so that 1) I can come back to it later and 2) so that others can interact with it and provide feedback if they like. I've seen some examples that use Medium.com but I kind of wanted something where I could have more control on the structure of the webpage and its contents. I might just have to learn to build my own website :

Comment: @user32882, then maybe [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)? I'll add that to my answer.